# How to couple datapoints in the same table based on timestamps?

Tags: mysql, unix-timestamp, large-data

I have a big mySQL table that contains values for all kinds of data (all with a different data_id) and a timestamp (unix timestamp in ms). I trying to build a (real-time) plotter for all this data and I want to be able to plot any data on the vertical axis against any other data on the horizontal axis. The problem I encouter is how to couple datapoints efficiently based on their timestamps.

The dataset is quite large and the logging frequency is about 10 Hz and I want a datapoint for every 1-5 minute. I already managed to make a (kinda) efficient SQL call to get an average value and an average timestamp for every 1 minute:

```
SELECT AVG(value), AVG(timestamp)
  FROM 
      (
        (
          SELECT value, timestamp
            FROM database 
           WHERE 
                 data_id = 100 AND
                 timestamp < ... and timestamp > ... 
        ORDER BY timestamp DESC
        ) as data
      )
GROUP BY timestamp DIV 60000
ORDER BY timestamp DESC;
```

However, now I want to be able to plot for example data_id 100 against data_id 200 instead of data_id 100 against time. So how do I couple the values for data_id 100 and 200 for a timestep of about 1 minute for a large dataset?

I already tried the following, but the SQL call took way too long...

```
SELECT a.timestamp, a.value, b.value 
  FROM 
      (
        SELECT value, timestamp 
          FROM daq_test.data_f32 
         WHERE
               data_id = 166 AND 
               timestamp < 1507720000000 AND
               timestamp > 1507334400000 
      ORDER BY timestamp DESC
      ) a,
      (
        SELECT value, timestamp 
          FROM daq_test.data_f32 
         WHERE
               data_id = 137 AND
               timestamp < 1507720000000 AND
               timestamp > 1507334400000 
      ORDER BY timestamp DESC
      ) b
WHERE a.timestamp DIV 60000 = b.timestamp DIV 60000
ORDER BY a.timestamp DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well i have no idea what is the point of this query. But my suggestion is to create an index based on your parameters in the WHERE clause.

So, if you are searching for records with data_id and timestamp, it is a good idea to create composite index based on those two columns.

Also the most significant slow down is probably caused by the ORDER BY timestamp.
Can you do EXPLAIN SELECT and edit your question so i can update the answer with more correct editing.